# Do equivalent matrices have the same image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, smith-normal-form

Let say we have R-module homomorphisms $T_1 ,T_2 : R^m \rightarrow R^n $ with matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively. If $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by just performing elementary column and row operations, must we have $\text{Im}(A)= \text{Im}(B)$ where $\text{Im}(A)= \{ Ax : x \in R^m \}.$

Comment: Row operations preserve the null space of a matrix, not the image. Vice versa for column operations. Perhaps you want a different equivalence relation, like [matrix similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{Im}(A)$ in your definition is essentially the subspace generated by the columns of $A.$ So if $B$ is obtained from $A$ by row operations, nothing can be guaranteed that $\mathrm{Im}(B) = \mathrm{Im}(A).$

For example, $A = \begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: Are they isomorphic in some sense?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the common sense. But concretely $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot A.$